# How to use GCC with increased compatibility

Tags: c++, gcc

I have installed the newest GCC on my 64-bit Linux machine but the shared libraries it produces are not compatible with older systems.

Specifically, I want to build with these parameters:

- The code must be 32-bit (x86/i686).
- ABI should be System V (not GNU).
- Required libstdc++ version should be at most GLIBCXX_3.4.13.

Is it possible to specify these options when `g++` is run, or do I need to rebuild GCC with `./configure` options?

Comment: One way is to link statically or ship the shared libraries with your executable. What you ask for may be doable, but most difficult.

Comment: I can link statically, but the System V ABI is still an issue.

Comment: Read [How to build GCC as a cross-compiler](https://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/).

Comment: What is the difference between GNU and System V ABI? Do you mean g++ dial ABI?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Static linking will resolve the library compatibility issue but OP would still need to address the cross-compilation.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin The difference is that with the GNU ABI, I get "elf file OS ABI invalid" on the target machine.

Comment: Cross-compile for x86 32-bit and check if the ABI error is resolved. Link stdc++ statically; the chance that it will match when cross-compiling is very low.

Comment: I was having the same problem, but with different systems. I solved it by linking *everything* statically (no need to cross-compile), but I had to replace glibc with an alternative implementation called musl. uClibc-ng might also work. Sounds much harder than it really was btw.

Comment: Also telling gcc to link statically does not always result in a static binary, (basically because glibc doesn't like to be linked statically) you could check using `ldd <your_binary_name>` whether your binary is truly static.